# JQuery to Vanilla JavaScript Conversion Is Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project which is totally based on vanilla JavaScript and the job of this tool is to check website responsiveness but the problem is that I have JQuery code of that problem and I am trying to convert it to pure JavaScript but it's not working at all so can you please take a look at this problem and give a proper solution for it ?

```js
(function($) {
  
  $(document).ready( function() {

    $('.devices').on('click', 'a', function() {
      var device_selected = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');
      
      $('.device').removeClass().addClass('device device-' + device_selected);
      
    })
    
  });

})(jQuery);


/*************** JS CODE (Not Working) ******************//*

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.querySelector('.devices').addEventListener('click', 'a', function() {
var device_selected = document.querySelector(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');
document.querySelector('.device').classList.remove().classList.add('device device-' + device_selected);
  });
});

*/
```

```css
.preview {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.preview .device {
  position: relative;
  width: 680px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.preview .device, .preview .device:after,
.preview .device iframe {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.preview .device iframe {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.preview .device:after {
  content: " ";
  background-color: #444;
  position: absolute;
}
.preview .device-desktop {
  width: 680px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 1em 1em 5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.preview .device-desktop:after {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 47.5%;
  border-radius: 100em;
}
.preview .device-desktop iframe {
  width: 1360px;
  height: 800px;
}
.preview .device-tablet-p {
  width: 384px;
  height: 512px;
  padding: 1em 1em 3em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.preview .device-tablet-p:after {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  bottom: 0.75em;
  left: 47%;
  border-radius: 100em;
}
.preview .device-tablet-p iframe {
  width: 768px;
  height: 1024px;
}
.preview .device-tablet-l {
  width: 512px;
  height: 384px;
  padding: 1em 3em 1em 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.preview .device-tablet-l:after {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  left: 93.5%;
  bottom: 47%;
  border-radius: 100em;
}
.preview .device-tablet-l iframe {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
}
.preview .device-mobile-p iframe,
.preview .device-mobile-l iframe {
  transform: scale(0.75);
}
.preview .device-mobile-p {
  width: 240px;
  height: 420px;
  padding: 1em 1em 3em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.preview .device-mobile-p:after {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  bottom: 0.5em;
  left: 45%;
  border-radius: 100em;
}
.preview .device-mobile-p iframe {
  width: 320px;
  height: 560px;
}
.preview .device-mobile-l {
  width: 420px;
  height: 240px;
  padding: 1em 3em 1em 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.preview .device-mobile-l:after {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  left: 91.5%;
  bottom: 45%;
  border-radius: 100em;
}
.preview .device-mobile-l iframe {
  width: 560px;
  height: 320px;
}
.preview iframe {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.devices {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 0 0 2rem;
  padding: 0;
}
.devices > li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <section class="preview">
  
    <ul class="devices">
      <li><a href="#desktop">Desktop</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tablet-p">Tablet</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tablet-l">Tablet Landscape</a></li>
      <li><a href="#mobile-p">Mobile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#mobile-l">Mobile Landscape</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="device device-desktop">
      <iframe src="https://www.lipsum.com/"></iframe>
    </div>
    
  </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Other potential issues aside, `document.querySelector(this)` looks very fishy. Also, "not working at all" isn't a good problem description, you should check for errors, debug it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

            const devices = document.querySelector(".devices");
            const device = document.querySelector(".device");

            devices.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                let element = e.target;
                if (element.nodeName === "A") {
                    let device_selected = element.getAttribute('href').replace('#', '');
                    // device.className = ''; // or device.removeAttribute('class');
                    device.className = 'device device-' + device_selected;
                }
            })
        });
```

Parts of the code in your vanilla is actually jQuery, like `.attr`.

Anyway, in your code, the event listener is on the entire `.devices` `ul`, and then only if an `<a>` tag is what was actually clicked, we act.
So that's what's being replicated here.

try clicking on, say, the bullets on the left. the function still runs but the `if` condition fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with help of `forEach()` method and `map()` method so check below snippet.

Helpful Links:
Add Class in JavaScript
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp

`forEach()` Method
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp

`map()` Method
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

`document.queryselectorall()` Method
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const device = document.querySelector(".device");
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.devices a')].forEach((elem)=>{
        elem.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // preventing
            [...document.querySelectorAll('.devices a')].map((r)=> r.classList.remove('active')); //remove active class
            this.classList.add('active'); // add active class
            let device_selected = this.getAttribute('href').replace('#', '');
            device.className = 'device device-' + device_selected;
        })
    });
});
```

```css
.preview {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.preview .device {
  position: relative;
  width: 680px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.preview .device, .preview .device:after,
.preview .device iframe {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.preview .device iframe {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.preview .device:after {
  content: " ";
  background-color: #444;
  position: absolute;
}
.preview .device-desktop {
  width: 680px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 1em 1em 5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.preview .device-desktop:after {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 47.5%;
  border-radius: 100em;
}
.preview .device-desktop iframe {
  width: 1360px;
  height: 800px;
}
.preview .device-tablet-p {
  width: 384px;
  height: 512px;
  padding: 1em 1em 3em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.preview .device-tablet-p:after {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  bottom: 0.75em;
  left: 47%;
  border-radius: 100em;
}
.preview .device-tablet-p iframe {
  width: 768px;
  height: 1024px;
}
.preview .device-tablet-l {
  width: 512px;
  height: 384px;
  padding: 1em 3em 1em 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.preview .device-tablet-l:after {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  left: 93.5%;
  bottom: 47%;
  border-radius: 100em;
}
.preview .device-tablet-l iframe {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
}
.preview .device-mobile-p iframe,
.preview .device-mobile-l iframe {
  transform: scale(0.75);
}
.preview .device-mobile-p {
  width: 240px;
  height: 420px;
  padding: 1em 1em 3em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.preview .device-mobile-p:after {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  bottom: 0.5em;
  left: 45%;
  border-radius: 100em;
}
.preview .device-mobile-p iframe {
  width: 320px;
  height: 560px;
}
.preview .device-mobile-l {
  width: 420px;
  height: 240px;
  padding: 1em 3em 1em 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.preview .device-mobile-l:after {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  left: 91.5%;
  bottom: 45%;
  border-radius: 100em;
}
.preview .device-mobile-l iframe {
  width: 560px;
  height: 320px;
}
.preview iframe {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.devices {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 0 0 2rem;
  padding: 0;
}
.devices > li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}
.devices > li a{
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
.devices > li a.active{
    padding: 5px 0;
    color: #183ec5;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #183ec5;
}
```

```html
<section class="preview">
    <ul class="devices">
        <li><a href="#desktop" class="active">Desktop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tablet-p">Tablet</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tablet-l">Tablet Landscape</a></li>
        <li><a href="#mobile-p">Mobile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#mobile-l">Mobile Landscape</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="device device-desktop">
        <iframe src="https://www.lipsum.com/"></iframe>
    </div>
</section>
```